# In elasticsearch mappings, what does the "index" attribute do for non-string types?

Tags: elasticsearch

In an elasticsearch mapping, the "index" attribute for strings determines if the string will be broken into tokens and analyzed.  What does settings the "index" attribute do for non-string types, like integers, floats, dates, etc?

Answer (score 0):

You can set "index" to "no" to turn off the ability to search by a specific field - the field will not be indexed. The default is "not_analyzed" which will index the data as is without analysis, so that you can search by that field. "analyzed" is not supported for numbers and dates:

> The other simple types — long, double, date etc — also accept the
>   index parameter, but the only relevant values are no and not_analyzed,
>   as their values are never analyzed.

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/mapping-intro.html

> **number and date**
>
> **index**
>
> Set to no if the value should not be indexed. Setting to no disables
>   include_in_all. If set to no the field should be either
>   stored in _source, have include_in_all enabled, or store be set to
>   true for this to be useful.

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-core-types.html

Answer (score 0):

"index" attribute for String type (from [es reference](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-core-types.html)):

> Set to analyzed for the field to be indexed and searchable after being
>   broken down into token using an analyzer. not_analyzed means that its
>   still searchable, but does not go through any analysis process or
>   broken down into tokens. no means that it won’t be searchable at all
>   (as an individual field; it may still be included in _all). Setting to
>   no disables include_in_all. Defaults to analyzed.

for other types:

> Set to no if the value should not be indexed. Setting to no disables include_in_all. If set to no the field should be either stored in _source, have include_in_all enabled, or store be set to true for this to be useful.

Answer (score 0):

For non-string values it disables indexing of that value and disables `include_in_all`. It means you won't be able to use that field in searches.

The value will still be stored so you can specify that field to be returned in your search request

```
{... "fields" : ["name", "age"] ...}
```

and you can read that value and use it in you app. (if you don't exclude it from `_source` it will be stored also there).